# Не могу подключить pfsense openvpn client к Zentyal

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

PFSense 2.4.4-RELEASE
Zentyal 5.1.1

Пытаюсь настроить следующую схему:
Zentyal - Openvpn server. 
PFSense - Openvpn client.
Надо пустить весь трафик через Openvpn сервер, но не получается подключить правильно клиент.

На Pfsense подключил сертификаты, создал подключение и даже подключился, Status показывает UP. Но я не пингую шлюз 192.168.160.1 (это шлюз VPN), соответственно трафик через VPN не идет. На стороне Zentyal так же не пингует клиента.
Пробовал подключить конфиг freeopenvpn - все работает, единственное там схема подключение через tls key.
На ноутбуке с Linux конфиг работает.

Конфиг клиента:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote  X.X.X.X 11194
float
remote-random
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca   "cacert.pem"
cert "15543325D277D897.pem"
key  "PFsense.pem"
verify-x509-name vpn-ORG name
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: Поправка к информации: Сменил порт подключения и конфиг на ноутбуке и маршрут через шлюз не создался... получается та же проблема. Значит что-то с zentyal...

Answer (score 0):

1) Если установить vpn как DG - тогда с сервера PFSense все работает и все пингуется, но интернета в локалке нет
2) Устанавливаем VPN без DG - на уровне PfSense добавляем как отельный маршрут и нужный трафик загоняем на него
В целом все получилось все работает как часы